# Spark mapPartitions Issue

Tags: apache-spark

I am using spark mapPartition on my DF and the use case i should submit one Job (either calling lambda or sending a SQS Message) for each Partition.

I am partitioning on a custom formatted date column and logging the no.of partitions before and after and it is working as expected.

How ever when i see the total no.of jobs it is more than the no.of partitions. For Some of the partitions there are two or three jobs !!

Here is the Code i am using

```
val yearMonthQueryRDD = yearMonthQueryDF.rdd.mapPartitions(
         partition => {
          val partitionObjectList = new java.util.ArrayList[String]()
          logger.info("partitionIndex = {}",TaskContext.getPartitionId());
          val partitionCounter:AtomicLong = new AtomicLong(0)
          val partitionSize:AtomicLong = new AtomicLong(0)
          val paritionColumnName:AtomicReference[String] = new AtomicReference[String]();

      // Iterate the Objects in a given parittion 
      val updatedPartition = partition.map( record => {
            import yearMonthQueryDF.sparkSession.implicits._
            partitionCounter.set(partitionCounter.get()+1)
            val recordSizeInt = Integer.parseInt(record.getAs("object_size"))
            val recordSize:Long = recordSizeInt.toLong
            partitionObjectList.add(record.getAs("object_key"))
            paritionColumnName.set(record.getAs("partition_column_name"))
            record
        }
      ).toList
      
       logger_ref.info("No.of Elements in Partition ["+paritionColumnName.get()+"] are =["+partitionCounter.get()+"] Total Size=["+partitionSize.get()+"]")
       // Submit a Job for the parition
       // jobUtil.submitJob(paritionColumnName.get(),partitionObjectList,partitionSize.get())
       updatedPartition.toIterator
    }
  )
```

Another thing that is making the debugging harder is the logging statements inside the mapPartitions() method are not found in the container error logs (since they are executed on each worker node not on master node i expected them to find them in container logs rather than in master node logs. Need to figure why i am only seeing stderr logs but not stdout logs on the containers though).

Thanks
Sateesh

Comment: Might want to show the UI stuff.

Comment: What's the point of it all?

Comment: Based on my understanding if there are n partitions in the DF after repartitioning on a column (in my case "paritition_column_name" ) submitJob should be only called for exactly "n" no.of times. When i checked AWS Batch (to where i am submitting the Jobs) i am seeing more than "n". Unable to confirm yet whether Spark it self is submitting more than "n" (still trying to figure out where EMR is storing the logging info).

Comment: Spark is submitting more than one Job for every Partition ( Not all the partitions though). When i checked the container logs i see the repeated logging statements for the same partition. If they are in different container logs (since they might be assigned to different worker nodes i understand it. But not sure why with the same container i see multiple for same partition !!)